# how to get object value of selection field in odoo @api.onchange

Tags: python, odoo, erp, odoo-12

i've a selection field with One2many relation i would like to modify another field upon the result of selection field but it returns object!!! anybody knows how to work it

```
 from odoo import models, fields, api

 class module1(models.Model):
   _name = 'module1_module1'
   _rec_name="sem"

   sem=fields.Selection([
    ('1', '1st Sem'),
    ('2', '2nd Sem'),
    ('3', '3rd Sem')
],"Semester")
  sem_id = fields.Char("Semester ID")
  sub = fields.One2many('module1_module1_1','sem',"Subjects")




  class module1_1(models.Model):
     _name = 'module1_module1_1'


     sem = fields.Many2one('module1_module1',"semester")
     sem_id = fields.Many2one('module1_module1',"ID")

     @api.onchange('sem')
     def _ValueCount(self):
        print(self.sem.sem)
```

Printing the selection field returns module1_module1(,)
i need specific field name like option 1 or 2 to condition accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Here you need to take care or avoid numeric key in selection field declaration.

```
   sem = fields.Selection([
       ('first', '1st Sem'),
       ('second', '2nd Sem'),
       ('third', '3rd Sem')
   ], "Semester")
```

Here is onchange method:

```
 @api.onchange('sem')
 def _ValueCount(self):
    # execute your logic base on semester
    if self.sem:
        sem = self.sem.sem
        if sem == 'first':
            #execute first semester logic
            ...
        elif sem == 'second':
            #execute second semester logic
            ...
        else:
            #execute third semester logic
            ...
```

Comment: apperantly that's not how things work in selection field